# Probability of Chi-squared distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, math-software, chi-squared

If I want to find $P(\chi^2(20)<23)$, does this mean that there are assumed to be $20$ degrees of freedom, with some cumulative range of $23$?

That is, in $R$, should one use the command pchisq$(23, 20)$ or pchisq$(23^2, 20)$?

Somewhat confused.

Comment: Maybe it is helpful to point out (and to remember) explicitly that the word "sq" and the superscript "2" in $\chi ^2$ are inherently part of the name of the distribution. The corresponding statistics computed do involve sum of squares (of "standardized deviations") and hence the square in the name - but this is irrelevant in what you are trying to compute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first command is correct.

In R `pchisq()` function gives the cumulative probabilities. In $P(\chi^{2}(20)<23)$, the degrees of freedom is 20 and 23 is the quantile value. R's `pchisq()` requires the quantile value as its first argument and degrees of freedom as the second argument. In other words, the value of $P(\chi^{2}(20)<23)$ is obtained on using the command `pchisq(23,20)`.

```
> pchisq(23,20)
```

[1] 0.7112055

> 